# Classic ASP + Ajax Form - success function not working, complete is ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

With Ajax and JS/Jquery I'm trying to send a simple Contact form to a Classic ASP (aspemail) and sent a messagem from a page **without reload**.

```
  <form id="form-submit" action="ASPEmail.asp" method="post">
    Name<br>
    <input id="name" type="text"><br>
    E-mail<br>
    <input id="email" type="text"><br>
    Message:<br>
    <textarea id="msg"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="SEND">
    <img src="loading.gif" class="loading">
   </form>
```

My ASPEMAIL.ASP is only test asp and I write only:

```
<% 
Response.Write("ok")
%>
```

And my JQuery Script:

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

   $("#form-submit").submit(function() {
      var data = $(this).serialize(),
          action = $(this).attr("action"),
          method = $(this).attr("method");

      $(".loading").show(); // show loading div
      $.ajax({
         url: action,
         type: method,
         data: data,
         success: function(data) {

            if(data === "ok")
            {
             document.location = "final.asp";
            }

         },
         error: function(err) {
             // there was something not right...
         },
         complete: function() {
            $(".loading").hide(); // hide the loading
         }
      });

      return false; // don't let the form be submitted
   });

});
</script>
```

I put a redirect on success to test (My objective is a message only) - but nothing happens.

But after send the "LOADING" appears on screen and hide and then the submit and "complete" is working.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What does `data` return when you log it in the console? (In `succes: function(data) {}`, before the `if` function?

Comment: [Check the browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) to see what exactly is happening; the network tab in particular.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 variables named data, try using a different variable here, as I believe you're "confusing" javascript here :)

```
 success: function(dataReturned) {

            if(dataReturned === "ok")
            {
             document.location = "final.asp";
            }

         },
```